# How to submit form with method post in angular 2 using formgroup

Tags: angular, post, angular-forms

I am trying to make a post request in angular, but as i found out, I can not do that, if I use `[formGroup]`, because submit button does nothing. My code looks like that

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" action="https://someUrl.com" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="lang" id="lang" value="en" formControlName = "lang" >
    <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

If I remove `formGroup` module, it works fine. Is there a bug, a submit override or something?

Answer (score 4):

you may use form group as shown below so as to submit form values to the backend.

**some-item.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SomeItemService } from './some-item.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'some-item',
    templateUrl: './some-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./some-item.component.css']
})

export class SomeItemComponent implements OnInit {
 someForm: FormGroup;

 constructor(private someItemService: SomeItemService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.createForm();
 }

 private createForm() {
   this.someForm= new FormGroup({
      field_one: new FormControl(''),
      field_two: new FormControl('')
   });
 }

 submitFunc() {
    this.someItemService.submitForm(this.someForm.value)
                .subscribe(
                    (data) => {
                       console.log('Form submitted successfully');                           
                    },
                    (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                );
        }
 }

}
```

**some-item.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="someForm" (ngSubmit)="submitFunc()">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="field_one"/>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="field_two"/>
  <button type="submit" [disabled] ="!someForm.valid" class="btn btn-success"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

**some-item.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class SomeItemService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }

 submitForm(data): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.post<any>(api-url, data);
 }

}
```

On submission of the form, the values can be accessed in the component and can be passed to the backend via service. I hope the point is clear by now.

Comment: what would Service.submitForm() do in that case? I previously tried to just call a function in service which would make a request but didn't work as i would want it to.

Comment: That would reach out to the backend to fetch or post data. I have updated the answer with minimal code for the same.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to use Reactive forms for init and validating, while still using the browser to post to server. This worked for me:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="form" >
    <form ngNoForm action="ui-api/setup" method="POST">
        <-- fields -->
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="resetForm()">Reset</button>
    </form>
</form>
```

Comment: nesting form in form ?

Answer (score 1):

Tadej, in Angular, usually you have some like

**component.html**

```
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (submit)="submit(formGroup)">
        <input type="text" name="lang" id="lang" value="en" formControlName = "lang" >
        <input type="submit" >
    </form>
```

**component.ts**

```
    constructor(http:HttpClient){}
    submit(formGroup)
    {
        if (formGroup.valid)
        {
             this.http.post("https://someUrl.com",formGroup.value).subscribe(res=>{
                   //here you received the response of your post
                   console.log(res);
                   //you can do asomething, like
                   alert("datos enviados");
             })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit it, using ngSubmit directive like that:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="formGroup" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="lang" id="lang" value="en" formControlName = "lang" >
    <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

and inside of component create **onSubmit** function:

```
onSubmit(){
   // here you make ajax request using http client
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl/#configure-the-control-to-update-on-a-submit-event, you can set up your form control to update your form group on submit:

```
searchInput: new FormControl('', { updateOn: 'submit' })
```

For example:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.primarySearch = new FormGroup({
        searchInput: new FormControl('', { updateOn: 'submit' }),
    });
    this.primarySearchSub();
}

primarySearchSub() {
    const primarySearchChange = this.primarySearch.valueChanges;
    primarySearchChange.subscribe(input => {
        console.log(input)
        // Perform your POST here //
    });
}
```

With:

```
<form [formGroup]="primarySearch">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input autocomplete="off" matInput formControlName="searchInput" />
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the normal html form behavior, but for this to work you need to remove FormsModule from your module, if you're already using FormsModule you could create a new module and put your new component there . For me it worked perfectly so I can use FormsModule in other modules and use the normal html form.

```
<form action="https://someUrl.com" method="post">
<input type="text" name="lang" id="lang" value="en">
<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

I removed Form group and form control from your code now you go to app.module.ts and in imports

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    **FormsModule**
  ],
```

If you create a new module be sure not to include FormsModule.